# Codeigniter Controller class login form : 404 page not found

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-form-helper

Im trying to combine several tutorials about Codeigniter and bootstrap and understand per codes so i can integrate it in my project. What i am trying to do right now is create a login form using the two framework.

And i setup my View according to the turotial included in Codeigniter  'user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html' which my landing page is named as 'home.php' is inside the folder 'pages' and header.php, and footer.php is inside the 'templates' folder. I created also a controller: Page.php.

I also use .htaccess to hide 'index.php'.  Now i follow this tutorial how to create a login page:
http://learnjquerybootstrap.blogspot.com/2015/01/login-session-using-codeigniter-and-bootstrap.html?m=1

-the only difference is this since i use htaccess:

```
<?php echo form_open(clogin/index); ?>
```

But when I  try to submit the page i receive a: 404 page not found. 
My navbar links are working fine. I understand that the codeigniter works like this:

http://localhost/myfolder/index.php/class/function/

so when i submit my form the url that show up is:

http://localhost/myfolder/clogin/index

and gives me: 404 page not found.

Question:
What is wrong with it?
is there something wrong with the tutorial that i am using? i check other tutorials and the controller structure is just the same, like on this link:

http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/08/how-to-create-login-form-codeigniter-mysql-twitter-bootstrap.html

do i need to include clogin.php in route.php?
or is it about the htaccess? my

```
uri_protocol
```

is configured as

```
'REQUEST_URI'
```

in config.php. i tried other options but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already firgured it out.The mistake was in the route.php, since i tried to combine two examples.. i realized that the wildcard route that i included from the Codeigniter user guide will not work with the Clogin.php.

Since it was set  as

`$route['(:any)']='pages/view/$1';`

So the  url works as

`http://localhost/myfolder/pages/view/clogin`

instead of

`http://localhost/myfolder/clogin`.

I removed it and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need include to route.
I recommented ready auth library.
If you use DevTools in your browser maybe "Network" tab of devtools can help you to why you get 404 error.

Comment: it is not included right now. but ill try to check on it

Comment: i checked on dev tools  and there are no errors  or message about it